Timezone mixing Hibernate, MapStruct, Spring
I'm getting frustrated with an issue that I want to resolve, but it's becoming very confusing.
This is what I'm trying to achieve:
Save dates in the database with timezone information.
Input/Output in DTOs should ALWAYS be treated as Europe/Rome.

This seems a bit challenging for me.
My database date columns were initially set as "timestamp", but I changed them to "timestamptz".
My Entity date is of type java.util.Date.
My DTO date is of type java.util.Date.
The problem arises when I run the application on my machine (GMT+2/+1 based on CEST/CET) and on an AWS machine (UTC).
Now, I want to handle dates globally, without manually converting each date field to my timezone and vice-versa.
I have heard about LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime, but I am unable to use them with my current knowledge. Additionally, there is another problem: some dates are marked as "@CreationTimestamp" on entity, which should also follow the same logic.
